# Change order value

Tags: r, sorting

I have a DB like this:

```
a <-c(4, 2, 10, 2, 10, 6, 2)
b <-c(4, 6, 70, 8, 18, 4, 3)
rbind(a,b)
```

I can create something like this:

```
x <- (4, 4, 2, 6, 10, 70, 2, 8, 10, 18, 6, 4, 3)
```

A DB that contains a and b order in this way, it is possible? I need to do a time series and the value must be in the same position

Comment: You were almost correct.  just need to just append with `c` i.e. `c(rbind(a,b))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rbind` works only when both the `vector`s are of the same length or else it will give unexpected output. i.e.

```
> rbind(c(4, 3, 5), c(3, 4))
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    4    3    5
[2,]    3    4    3
Warning message:
In rbind(c(4, 3, 5), c(3, 4)) :
  number of columns of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 2)
```

and when we do `c` to make a vector, it returns an extra `3` from `recycling`

---

A more general approach is to `order` based on the `sequence` of values in both `vector` while `c`oncatenating the `vector`s`

```
c(a, b)[order(c(seq_along(a), seq_along(b)))]
[1]  4  4  2  6 10 70  2  8 10 18  6  4  2  3
```